# File checker in unix and storing the only files available to another variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hive

Hive Table stores the Metadata of source files:

```
Hive_Table: SRC_Meta
Col_Table_Name  Col_SRCFILENAME_Name    col_Header_Names
Table1          FileName1               col1 string, col2 bigint........
Table2          FileName2
...
.
.

.
.
Table100        FileName100
```

Unix FIle Location: Files are getting dropped over here and Not all 100 Source files will be available all the time. let's say If I received 5 to 6 files out of 100+

```
Source files.
/tmp/Filename1.txt
/tmp/FileName13.txt
/tmp/FileName19.txt
/tmp/Filename81.txt
/tmp/FileName94.txt
```

Using The Metadata table from Hive, extracted SRCFILENAMEnames and saved it to variable and then usinf for loop passing over it to the file checker if available prints with available, if not file not available

```
SRCFILE=($(hive -S -e "SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RTRIM(Col_SRCFILENAME_Name))
FROM SRC_Meta))

for SRCFILENAME in "${SRCFILE[@]}"
do

echo "SRCFILENAME NAME IS $SRCFILENAME"

if  ls ${SRCFILENAME}*.txt 1> /dev/null 2>&1;  then

mv -f ${SRCFILENAME}*.txt /tmp/archive/

echo "***************File is available and moved to the Script source dir*********"

else
echo "${SRCFILENAME} not found in the Source directory"
echo
echo
fi

done
```

Issue 1: But I have to deal with case insensitive where finding out the file names irrespective of upper and lower case in unix folder when searching from Hive and tried with this one

```
if  ls `ls | grep -i ${SRCFILENAME}*.txt` 1> /dev/null 2>&1;  then
```

The above one is not working as expected while fetching out the

Issue 2: After moving out the files to archive folder, I have to create table using SRCFILENAME variable, but I have to fetch the table name again from hive table
and have to do for loop .

In this scenario passing the 100+ tables again using SRCFILENAME one by one is time consuming, instead is there way to bypass and minimize and only pass the **available SRCFILENAME's** as **variable** to fetch rest of the meta information to create hive tables? Assuming there will be other files in `/tmp/archive/` folder

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is one item worth reading. [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) is another.

Comment: And fix the missing quotes in your code as-given here; the lack of them is throwing off the syntax highlighting, not to mention creating a new bug additional to the one you're intending to ask about.

Comment: Beyond that -- if you care about performance, one of the most important things to do is eliminate external command invocations. That's part of why you shouldn't use `ls` -- it's far slower than a shell-builtin test (like `set -- "$SRCFILENAME"*.txt && [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]]`). And if you generate a list with everything you want to move, you can move them with the smallest possible number of `mv` invocations all at once, as with (assuming GNU `mv`) `printf '%s\0' "${files_to_move[@]}" | xargs -0 mv -t /tmp/archive --`.

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps shell variables are in a space reserved for names meaningful to the shell or OS-provided tools; it's better form to have your own names contain at least one lower-case character. See the POSIX standard @ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a single namespace.